# Rails correctly deleting database item but still raising error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have an issue with my database in a Rails app.
The problem is when I press delete on an uploaded image that it raises the error in the browser, shown below.
What is confusing me is:
A) When I check the items using the Rails console, it shows the item has been deleted.
B) The error refers to items that never existed, ie, `id=3` when there were only ever two items present.

## Error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#destroy
Couldn't find Post with id=4
Extracted source (around line #24):

def destroy
 @post = Post.find params[:id]
 @post.destroy
 redirect_to 'posts/'
end
```

## Posts Controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController


def index
 @posts = Post.all
end

def new
  authenticate_user!
  @post = Post.new
end

def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  if @post.save
    redirect_to '/posts'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def destroy
  @post = Post.find params[:id]
  @post.destroy
  redirect_to 'posts/'
end

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:description, :picture)
end

end
```

## Post Model

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :picture, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }

  validates :description, presence: true
  validates_attachment_content_type :picture, content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg",     "image/png"]

  has_many :comments
end
```

## Create Posts Migrate

```
 class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
   create_table :posts do |t|
   t.text :description

  t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Not sure what exactly is going wrong, but it seems to be raising an error on a method that is to all intents and purposes working just fine and also something appears to be going wrong with the id assignment in the database.

Comment: this issue is your post could not found with id 4.Please check this post is really exists in your DB or not?

Comment: Can you share the Delete link code from the view clicking on which you get this error.

Comment: I think you are not sending params id...please check once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:--

In **Posts Controller**

```
def destroy
 @post = Post.find params[:id]
 @post.destroy
 redirect_to '/posts'
end
```

If above doesnot work then try the below

```
def destroy
 @post = Post.find params[:id]
 @post.destroy
 redirect_to posts_path
end
```

Comment: yeah that was it. First solution worked, second solution threw the same error.
Forward slash in the wrong place. I'm an idiot!
The database is still counting upwards though. Is this normal?
On id=7 when I was trying that solution, even though there have only ever been two items in the database
Would it only revert back to 0 if I reset the database?